# PHP Sessions: XAMPP Apache PHP Sessions persists even if I restart PC

Tags: php, apache, xampp, persistence, session-variables

I have a problem because Session variables are persisting even after I close the browser, shut down apache and restart the computer.

I am storing a user_id session variable if the users logs in.  However I did not implement a logout yet.  In any case, the sessions should not persists after I restart my PC.

In php.ini the session cookie lifetime is set to 0.  Here's a copy paste:

```
; Lifetime in seconds of cookie or, if 0, until browser is restarted.
; http://php.net/session.cookie-lifetime
session.cookie_lifetime=0
```

Any ideas?  This is the way I create the session variables:

```
if (!isset($_SESSION))
{
      session_start();
}
$_SESSION["username"] = $username;
```

Thank you

Comment: change to this if (!isset($_SESSION["username"] )){ } and use session_destroy(); for destroy.

Comment: Can you specify the value of  "session.save_path"  in your php conf file?

Comment: @KheshavSewnundun its session.save_path="D:\Users\Ramon\Dropbox\xampp\tmp" .. Basically the xampp path plus the tmp folder

Answer (score 0):

I know it is a 4 year old question but I have a workaround in case anyone is still looking.
I created a file in the project folder called 'end.php' with the following code

```
session_start();
session_destroy();
echo "Goodbye!";
```

I can call it whenever I need to restart the session.
Cheers.